# Move di container into his own project in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I'm building an API in .NET Core 3.1. I  try to decouple this project in the typical 3 layers. Instead of having an UI layer, I have the API project with the controllers. I also have a class library project for the logic, and another class library project as the data access layer.

I'm trying to use dependency injection over all projects. My problem is, that I have, until now, registered my interfaces and classes as services in the `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs`, in my API project.

But that would mean, that the logic, and the data access layer would reference the API project. To solve this, I thought, it would be the best, if I move the DI container into his own "mapping" class library project and reference this in all other projects. Would that be a good practice?

If yes, how could such a project look like, how to setup the container and how will it be instantiated in the API's project `ConfigureServices` method in `startup.cs`?

Comment: Leave the container in the startup.cs (API layer), but have that call a function (with the IServiceCollection), in the data layer, which then registers it's own services.

Comment: @Neil thanks for your answer, but then I also have to do the same with the logic layer. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: What I generally do is the Presentation layer (API) would call the logic layer, and the logic layer would call the data layer.

Comment: @Neil and build like a "reference" chain.  I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that would mean, that the logic, and the data access layer would
> reference the API project

I don't think it should, just opposite, API project will be solution entry point, sole project which "knows" about all other dependencies and glue them together.

Other projects need to reference [IServiceCollection Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicecollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), which can be done by installing `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` NuGet package.

Every project can introduce own "registration" method, which can be called by entry point.

```
// In Logic project
public IServiceCollection AddLogic()
{
    services.AddSingleton<MyLogic>();
    // Add other logic types

    return services;
}

// In Data project
public IServiceCollection AddDataAccess(string connectionString)
{
    services.AddTransient<IRepository, SqlRepository>();
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    return services
}

// Startup
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase");
services.AddLogic();
services.AddDataAccess(connectionString);
```

Only way where other projects need to reference API project is when you are using some types from API project. If this the case, then move them to the project where they are going to be used or introduce another project which both API and other project can reference.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried that and I think I understand that. But, what if I need to call a, lets say, handlerclass from my data project inside the logic project? Then I have to reference the Data project, to inject the handlerclass in the constructor of the logic class, right? I'm sorry, I'm so confused right now, I've read so much stuff the last days.

Comment: And I think I had a misconception, because you are right, the other projects don't need to reference the api project, the api project needs to reference the others, or just one, if I put my registrations in that one project.